# Excel VBA paste to offset of activecell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code in UserForm for copy pasting values from one worksheet to active cell.

I would like to copy paste to active cell offset. Cell that is in offset to paste in is located 1 cell to the left and 10 cells up.

1) Copy L67 from Worksheet "Other Data" to Active Cell

2) Copy Q67 from Worksheet "Other Data" to Active Cell Offset (-1,-10)

My code that I have tried:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

'Paste to a Defined Range
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("L67").Copy

'Offset Paste (offsets 2 cells down and 1 to the right
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("Q67").Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -10).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

I receive an error on:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -10).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got the offsets the wrong way round. The first number is rows, the second is columns, so it would be:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(-10, -1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```