# Copying the shape from one sheet to another with offset in pixels

Tags: excel, vba

Good afternoon,

I would like to copy the element from one sheet to another.
This is a simple issue when we are basing on the rough cell range.
In my case, the issue doesn't look simple, because I want to have some offset.

The query provided here:
[Excel VBA paste to offset of activecell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54019244/excel-vba-paste-to-offset-of-activecell)

doesn't really solve my problem, since it shows the offset by whole cells.

I want to have an offset in pixels rather than cells. The details are below. The dark arrow shows the object, which I managed to paste in my sheet. The red arrow shows the target location of this object. It can't stick to the cell range, unfortunately.

[image]

My code so far looks like this:

```
 Sub Divider()
 Sheets("Cables 1").Shapes("Divider1").Copy
 Location ActiveSheet.Range("B25").PasteSpecial
 Selection.Name = "Divider"
 End Sub

 Function Location(s, Target As Range)
 s.Left = Target.Left + 3
 s.Top = Target.Top - 1
 End Function
```

Unfortunately, the debugger doesn't tolerate the function name before the `ActiveSheet`. I am getting an error instead.
**Argument not optional**

Is there some way to make this small offset?

Comment: `Location` expects two arguments... You need to pass it a `Shape` and a `Range`. You're not doing either of those.

Comment: You mean DIM them?

Comment: No... you need to pass location two arguments: Right now you have `ActiveSheet.Range("B25").PasteSpecial`, which is not an argument at all. Well it is an argument, but not a shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Sub Divider()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Shp As Shape

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet

    Sheets("Cables 1").Shapes("Divider1").Copy
    Ws.Range("B25").PasteSpecial
    Selection.Name = "Divider"

    Set Shp = Ws.Shapes("Divider")
    Location Shp, Range("b25:L50")
End Sub

Function Location(s As Shape, Target As Range)
    With s
        .Left = Target.Left + 3
        .Top = Target.Top + 3
        .Width = Target.Width - 6
        '.Height = Target.Height - 6
    End With
End Function
```